# Using the flashText library to count occurrences of characters in a book

Tags: python

I am using a windows machine running python 3.7.4.
Currently I am trying to use the `flashText` library to process a .txt file to count the number of occurrences of characters that I selected and running into errors while processing the file.

My code is as follows

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
#making a dictionary of major charaters
#a few major players for now
keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor(case_sensitive=False)

keyword_dict = {
    "Eddard" : ["ned", "eddard"],
    "Daenerys" : ["dany", "khaleesi"],
    "john" : ["john snow", "bastard"],
    "Tyrion" : ['imp', 'halfman' , 'tyrion Lannister' ],
    "bran" : ['bran stark']

 }
keyword_processor.add_keywords_from_dict(keyword_dict)
text_file = open("gameofthrones.txt", "r" , encoding="utf8")

keywords_found = keyword_processor.extract_keywords(text_file)
print(keywords_found)

text_file.close()
```

I am getting an error that I don't quite understand:

```
C:\Users\MLMir\Desktop\python>stackoverflow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MLMir\Desktop\python\stackoverflow.py", line 24, in <module>
    keywords_found = keyword_processor.extract_keywords(text_file)
  File "C:\Users\MLMir\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flashtext\keyword.py", line 475, in extract_keywords
    sentence = sentence.lower()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I've tried changing this to a list but that just threw a different attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

Need to read the text file in python after opening it.

Try below:

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
#making a dictionary of major charaters
#a few major players for now
keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor(case_sensitive=False)

keyword_dict = {
    "Eddard" : ["ned", "eddard"],
    "Daenerys" : ["dany", "khaleesi"],
    "john" : ["john snow", "bastard"],
    "Tyrion" : ['imp', 'halfman' , 'tyrion Lannister' ],
    "bran" : ['bran stark']

 }
keyword_processor.add_keywords_from_dict(keyword_dict)
text_file = open("gameofthrones.txt",'r', encoding="utf8")

raw = text_file.read()

keywords_found = keyword_processor.extract_keywords(raw)
print(keywords_found)

text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, it makes no sense to search an empty file for keywords.

Second, the method extract_keywords expects a string, not a file. lower is not a method of file.